Automatic video playback in desktop browsers: HTML5/Angular17, autoplay loop muted playsinline
Stack: Angular17
Desktop ❌ Doesnt work- No autoplay video
Mobile  ✅ Working - Autoplay video Working
I am working on a website for a client a requirement is the automatic playback of a video on the index page, I have tried this with this, but this does not work on desktop only on mobile
   <video  src="assets/video/intro.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline></video> 

but this does not autoplay the video, also I tried playing the video from ts with the property .play() but this doesn't work.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it? - (Why would you even link to NFSW websites on here...) - FWIW the video autoplays on Firefox 126.0 (64-bit)

I just wanted to give more information about the issue, because this problem is not common for me because with this code it should autoplay the video

Questions shouldn't relay on external sources as explained in the linked article

My Solution for this issue was:
<!-- HTML -->
<video class="elementor-video" src="assets/video/intro.mp4" autoplay="" loop="" muted="muted" playsinline="" controlslist="nodownload" #introVideo></video> 

@ViewChild('introVideo') introVideo!: ElementRef<HTMLVideoElement>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const video: HTMLVideoElement = this.introVideo.nativeElement;
    video.muted = true; // Ensuring the video is muted
    video.play().catch(error => {
      console.error('Error attempting to play video:', error);
    });
  }

